# How can disable, remove or force a prompt when clicking the application Close button in the title bar of Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I tried using [`Quit Control for VSCode`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=artdiniz.quitcontrol-vscode), but that doesn't do anything for an actual mouse click on the close `X`:

[image]

Is there a way to configure the behavior for the close button?